# VSCode git add failing on the full path

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I've run into an odd bug with VSCode. Recently whenever I attempt to add my changes to git staging via the VSCode UI I get the following error:

```
Git: fatal: c:\Projects\Demo-App\angular-front-end\src\app\app.module.ts: 'c:\Projects\Demo-App\angular-front-end\src\app\app.module.ts' is outside the repository.
```

If I go into the command line, I can manually add the files, but only if I shorten the file path.

Doesn't Work:

```
> git add c:\Projects\Demo-App\angular-front-end\src\app\app.module.ts
fatal: c:\Projects\Demo-App\angular-front-end\src\app\app.module.ts: 'c:\Projects\Demo-App\angular-front-end\src\app\app.module.ts' is outside repository
```

Works

```
> git add .\src\app\app.module.ts
```

I'm a bit lost as to why this is occurring, or how to fix this.

## Update

- Creating a brand new angular project displays the same issues in VS Code with git.
- Deleting the .git folder, and creating it again displays the same error

Comment: Have you cloned any repository in that location?

Comment: Where do you have your .gitignore and .git located?

Comment: .gitignore and .git are located at 'c:\Projects\Demo-App\angular-front-end\'.

I have cloned the repository, but the issue also persists in another project which I haven't cloned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLDR; **Upgrade Git first** (to 2.27), relaunch VSCode and see if the issue persist.

---

Make sure to add the folder which includes `.git/` to your VSCode workspace.
In your case: add `c:\Projects\Demo-App\angular-front-end`

If your workspace has `c:\` as a folder, it would not be able, as you have seen, to add files to a repository, since Git would need a relative path from the root folder of said repository.

There has been recent report of the [same issue after the latest VSCode update](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/99870#issuecomment-643040268), but make sure to update Git first (to 2.27).

Comment: I've removed the folder from the workspace, and re-added it, making sure I had the top folder structure including the .git. The issue still persists. I've also created a new angular project just to test git, and that also appears to be failing in visual studio code

Comment: @user3610520 Do you have any `.git` folder in one of the parent folders (like for instance directly under `C:\`)

Comment: @user3610520 What version of Git re you using?

Comment: git version 2.9.0.windows.1. Just noticed your link, so I will try updating it now and see if that fixes it

Comment: @user3610520 Yes, try again with Git 2.27 (https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases)

Comment: Yup! Upgrading from 2.9.0 to 2.27.0.windows.1 appears to have fixed the issue! Thanks

Comment: yup, same here.. updating to git 2.27 solved the issue